Automatically Enumerating Constants?
For a game I'm working on, suppose I have a class GameObject which has an unsigned int member representing its state. I also have some constants which represent the states that an instance of GameObject can have. For simplicity, suppose GameObject has the following states:
GAME_OBJECT_STATE_IDLE
GAME_OBJECT_STATE_SPAWN
GAME_OBJECT_STATE_MAX

I also have a member function which handles the behavior for each state, and a vector of pointers to these member functions such that every frame I can execute the correct state by just calling (this->*state_function[state])();
Next, suppose I have two more classes, Character and Projectile, both of which inherit from GameObject. They each inherit the states from GameObject, but they each add unique states outside of that. Character adds the following states:
CHARA_STATE_WALK
CHARA_STATE_JUMP
CHARA_STATE_MAX

Projectile adds the following states:
PROJECTILE_STATE_MOVE
PROJECTILE_STATE_MAX

Both CHARA_STATE_WALK and PROJECTILE_STATE_MOVE have a value equal to GAME_OBJECT_STATE_MAX, which doesn't actually have its own associated behavior. On construction, all 3 classes will resize the state_function vector to be the size of their respective _MAX constant.
With all of that in mind, I'm looking for a way to automatically set values for these states in such a way that satisfies all of the following requirements:

Each constant from each set has a value 1 higher than the previous one declared (E.G. GAME_OBJECT_STATE_IDLE = 0, GAME_OBJECT_STATE_SPAWN = 1, etc.)
The first constant for Character and Projectile has the same value as GAME_OBJECT_STATE_MAX
Values are shared between mutually exclusive states, I.E. CHARA_STATE_WALK and PROJECTILE_STATE_MOVE share a value.
The constants must be capable of being wrapped in an std::any without making a cast, and they must be capable of being unwrapped with a common call to any_cast (I.E. the constants must NOT be of type unnamed-enum, and if they are going to be implemented using a typed enum, any of the CHARA_STATE_ and PROJECTILE_STATE_ constants must implicitly cast down to whatever type the GAME_OBJECT_STATE_ constants end up being)
The constants must be usable in switch statements

Up until recently, my approach was to use both enums and const ints, and declared them likeso:
GameObjectState.h
#pragma once
enum {
    _GAME_OBJECT_STATE_IDLE,
    _GAME_OBJECT_STATE_SPAWN
    _GAME_OBJECT_STATE_MAX
};

const int GAME_OBJECT_STATE_IDLE = _GAME_OBJECT_STATE_IDLE;
const int GAME_OBJECT_STATE_SPAWN = _GAME_OBJECT_STATE_SPAWN;
const int GAME_OBJECT_STATE_MAX = _GAME_OBJECT_STATE_MAX;

CharaState.h
#pragma once
#include "GameObjectState.h"
enum {
    _CHARA_STATE_WALK = GAME_OBJECT_STATE_MAX,
    _CHARA_STATE_JUMP,
    _CHARA_STATE_MAX
};

const int CHARA_STATE_WALK = _CHARA_STATE_WALK;
const int CHARA_STATE_JUMP = _CHARA_STATE_JUMP;
const int CHARA_STATE_MAX = _CHARA_STATE_MAX;

This approach technically worked, but it was also gross to look at and made it very tedious to change the order these constants are declared in (which is the whole reason I want to auto-enumerate them rather than just manually specifying the 70 or so constants that the actual game uses). Recently I tried a different approach using constexprs, which looks like this:
GameObjectState.h
#pragma once

inline int GAME_OBJECT_STATE_NUM = 0;

constexpr int game_object_state_start() {
    GAME_OBJECT_STATE_NUM = 0;
    return GAME_OBJECT_STATE_NUM++;
}

constexpr int game_object_state() {
    return GAME_OBJECT_STATE_NUM++;
}

const int GAME_OBJECT_STATE_IDLE = game_object_state_start();
const int GAME_OBJECT_STATE_SPAWN = game_object_state();
const int GAME_OBJECT_STATE_MAX = game_object_state();

CharaState.h
#pragma once
#include "GameObjectState.h"

inline int CHARA_STATE_NUM = GAME_OBJECT_STATE_MAX;

constexpr int chara_state_start() {
    CHARA_STATE_NUM = GAME_OBJECT_STATE_MAX;
    return CHARA_STATE_NUM++;
}

constexpr int chara_state() {
    return CHARA_STATE_NUM++;
}

const int CHARA_STATE_WALK = chara_state_start();
const int CHARA_STATE_JUMP = chara_state();
const int CHARA_STATE_MAX = chara_state();

This approach is still a little gross since it requires the value of the _STATE_NUM to be reset every time the header where these constants are declared is imported (hence the "start" versions of the constexpr functions), but the bigger issue with this approach is that it causes the program not to actually view the states as constants, meaning they aren't usable in switch statements.
Is there a cleaner way to enumerate these constants automatically in a way that hits all of the requirements from earlier or should I just fold and go with the first approach I showed?

But only enum is enough, for what you use also const int here

As I said earlier, just using enums doesn't work because unnamed-enums are incompatible with std::any and the named enums would have to all be the same type while being declared in different places

Note that names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (_GAME_OBJECT_STATE_IDLE etc.) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Unnamed enums are compatible with std::any. They have a type just like named enums. That you don't want to declare the constants in the same place is what would make enums of either sort a bad fit.

Why are not your enums named? And why not enum classes? And why not explicitly specify underlying types? Using enum class you could shorten the values' names. If the underlying_type is common and used as the storage, switch can work perfect using std::to_underlying for each case.
